# How to specify caller file name in python logger

Tags: python, logging, format

i'm trying to create custom log that is based on python logger library.
Main goal is to create main log that can be called from any script all over the application and write log data to the same log file. 
the problem is that because logger is embedded into the custom class , each call of the function writes log data as if call were made from main file.

Lets say I have this code for custom log class:

```
import os
import logging
from logging import * 
from datetime import *


class omri_logging:

    @staticmethod
    def logcreate (severity = logging.DEBUG, filename =os.path.basename(__file__)):

        today = datetime.today()
        week = today.strftime("%U")
        LogName = 'MainLog' + week + '.log'
        FORMAT = "%(filename)s#%(levelname)s#%(asctime)s#%(funcName)s#%(lineno)d#%(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(filename=LogName,
                            level=severity,format=FORMAT,
                            )

    @staticmethod
    def CreateError (msg):
        logging.error(msg)
```

**logcreate** function will recieve file name where it were called. How do I change logger formater to put this file name as logged file. 
to get the following log example:

> omri_logger.py#DEBUG#2015-02-21 11:48:56,819##63#Error Message >Sent From File

to the following log line, consider that now the file name that CreateError called is LogCallFile.py

> LogCallFile.py#DEBUG#2015-02-21 11:48:56,819##63#Error Message >Sent From File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a separate python file say settings.py that holds log settings, and import it to your project file.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s(%(lineno)d) %(message)s')
my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(Logfile, mode='a', maxBytes=5*1024*1024,
                                 backupCount=5, encoding=None, delay=0)
my_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
my_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Use the below code in your project file after importing settings.py

```
app_log = logging.getLogger('root')
app_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app_log.addHandler(settings.my_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try put your global logging configuration in a file that you will import to your scripts and in each specific script add a `getLogger(name)` call:

```
logging.getLogger(name)
```

Where `name` can be a name of actual file that writes the log.

So you can also detect current file name like this for example:

```
name = (inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()).split("\\", -1)[-1]).rsplit(".", 1)[0] #Extract current *.py file name
```

Comment: Thank you for example. but that is not really what I mean, this is the code from another file that is called log.py for example: `import os
import comolog
from comolog import *

omri_logging.logcreate(logging.DEBUG)
omri_logging.CreatError("error")`   after logcreate called the log is greated. Another step is to write error with thew log.py name as filenami in format... How do I pass this data, because the line number, file name are all rely on custom log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to include the string passed as the filename kwarg and don't need to alter the logging parameter, you should be able to just insert your filename kwarg as a string in the format like this:

FORMAT = filename + "#%(levelname)s#%(asctime)s#%(funcName)s#%(lineno)d#%(message)s"

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But my main problem is that when i put only name the lines of log point for class file and not actual file...